# Как получить выбранный вариант spinner в Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Массив значений spinner'а, задан через string-array (статически).
Как в Java-коде сделать простейшую обработку, чтобы по событию выбора элемента спиннера показывался toast с текстом этого элемента?

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_values);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), choose[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: `String selected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: А на какое событие его повесить? Если вставить в onCreate, то это просто выведется при загрузке layout. Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String selected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: повешайте слушатель OnItemSelectedListener. больше [о спиннере](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php)

Comment: А почему тост появляется в момент загрузки layout? Нужно, чтобы он появлялся только при выборе элемента spinner. Добавил код выше.

Comment: перед установкой слушателя добавьте строку `spinner.setSelection(0,false);`. другие [варианты решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397933/android-spinner-avoid-onitemselected-calls-during-initialization)

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.